# Firebase security rules write to database with a given email

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How can I define my Firebase Security Rules for realtime database, that only users with a specific email can write data to the database?

Lets they there is a user with an email test@googlemail.com.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "shoes" : {
      ".write" : "auth != null && auth.token.email === '/test@googlemail.com/'"
    }
  }
}
```

This code works fine without **&& auth.token.email === '/test@googlemail.com/'**. But I want to specify this with an given email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "shoes" : {
      ".write" : "auth != null && auth.token.email === 'test@googlemail.com'"
    }
  }  
}
```